# Setting a custom hint for the email text in standard email dialog

Tags: android, email

I would like to bring up the Android standard email dialog with a custom hint for the email text (leaving the actual text empty). Is it possible ?

It it can't be done through Intent,  it may be possible to retrieve the template for email dialog, fill it with the necessary stuff, and send email using email API.

Comment: You might look for `setHint(int)` and in XML `android:hint="custom hint"` ?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to bring up the Android standard email dialog with a custom hint for the email text (leaving the actual text empty). Is it possible ?

There is no documented and supported means for doing this.